# Wordpress custom meta box loop destroys post slug

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, permalinks, meta-boxes

Now this is a crazy one. So bear with me...

I have a custom meta box. Inside it I have a post loop, that prints out another custom post type titles. I got everything to work, save etc. But now from that loop, the first posts title jumps into the permalink of the post I am editing.

I am using new WP_query to call the loop inside the metabox.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'meeskond');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
.........
<?php 
endwhile;
```

I have tried other ways to call the loop, nothing seems to remedy this.
As I understand the permalink is being populated right after my script runs. And somehow $page_name is taken out of my meta box loop.

Seems to me, that wp-admin/js/post.js is doing this, but I cant think of any way to fix it.
My brain is empty... Any pointers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found many answers, but found one that actually works.

Just changed my loop call inside my meta box to this.

```
global $post;

$filtArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'insert_brains',
);
$filts = get_posts($filtArgs);

$filtData = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $filtID, true );

foreach ( $filts as $filt ) : setup_postdata($filt);

    $filtID = 'filt_' . $filt->ID; 
    $filtTitle = $filt->post_title;
    ?>

    ....

<?php endforeach;
```

Big thanks to Gaz. It works like magic.
Stole his solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744150/custom-post-type-id-issue-when-querying-other-post-types?rq=1).